# nodejs error; "Use of const in strict mode" in Azure application log

Tags: node.js, azure

On deploying a node/react application to an Azure Windows app service I noticed the following error in the application log ..

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
```

Some older post suggest this is an issue with out-of-date node versions however, I am using node v18.3.0.  I have also seen it suggested that the flag '--strict_mode' should be passed to node but other posts suggest this is now irrelevant with newer versions of node as strict mode is enabled by default.

My Azure node version is WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION: "~18.3.0". I'm using typescript in my node application and my .tsconfig is as follows;

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "downlevelIteration": true
  }
}
```

While I understand what **strict mode** does and *why* this error occurs (in general) I'm just trying to understand what might be causing the error in Azure and how I might resolve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even I have noticed the same `javascript SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode`  then I configured the `"target": "es6"` and restarted my application now its working fine.

I had configured the **tsconfig** file same as like you.
[image]

- Then I updated application settings in azure portal as below.

[image]

- Now I didn't have any issues with above error and the web app is working fine.

[image]

Once changes are done in your application just wait for few minutes then re deploy the application.